# The most efficient way to generate -5V out of 5V3 at 30mA

Tags: dc-dc-converter, 5v

In my design, I need to power up a few op-amps with positive and negative rail. Taking into account amplitude in the signal path, headroom for input common-mode voltage, output voltage swing and voltage drop for LDOs on each rail I need at least 5V and -5V. Generating 5V out of 5V3 is the easy part. Generating -5V proves more difficult. Considering load current, I cannot use voltage multiplier or switch cap approach. The only possible solution I have at the moment is to use isolated DCDC converter (“dual-rail” schematic in the picture attached). Is there any other approach I could use?

[image]

Comment: What rail voltages do your op-amps use (after LDOs)?

Comment: Ideally 5V1 and -4V9 I intend to use low voltage drop LDOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really complicated to generate -5V out of a positive rail; as you've noted, inverting converters are a thing!

So, a non-isolated inverting converter is the way to go – these aren't inherently any less current-capable than an isolated converter, so there's something about your presumption that it'd be better to use an isolated converter that's not quite right.

Also, "a couple of opamps" doesn't sound like a lot of load at all, so probably pretty compact (and easy!) designs would do.

You can try out a lot of vendor tools for DC/DC converter design. I like TI's [webench](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/). I just hacked in Vin= 5.0 to 5.3 V, Vout = -5 V, Iout = 0.5 A, and got this within seconds (along with a few other proposed designs):

[image: DC/DC non-isolated inverting converter]

Comment: Thank you for the link to this TI tool. I must say it is amazing! 
Yes, true DCDC converter does not have to be insulated. I simply went back to the solution I used in past. However, I am glad I also asked for help and input. Clearly, I can achieve better efficiency at a lower cost with a non-insulated DCDC inverting converter.
I know that couple of op-amps don’t sound that bad however they are all high GBW and slew rate devices.

Comment: well, that really still doesn't "high average current", but more "good stabilizing / decoupling". I don't really see how they'd be using > 1A.